# Handling scroll in ListView with buttons

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a horizontal `ListView` where I would like to handle the scrolling differently than the usual scrollbar.

Right now a scrollbar appears when the items overflow. Instead I would like to detect this and add buttons on each side to do the scrolling, just as browsers do.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1"
               Name="NavList"
               ItemsSource="{x:Bind TabItems}"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
               IsItemClickEnabled="True"
               ItemClick="NavList_OnItemClick"
               ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleCustom}"
               SizeChanged="NavList_OnSizeChanged">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TabNavigationItem">
                       <Grid Height="48" Margin="4,0,4,0">
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Height="20" Text="{x:Bind Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
                            <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Width="14" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1,0,0" Visibility="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <Button Width="100" Height="100" Background="{StaticResource Transparent}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="TabCloseButton_OnClick" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE711;" FontSize="100" Foreground="{StaticResource Text-Black}"></FontIcon>
                                </Button>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <controls:WrapPanel HorizontalSpacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="48"></controls:WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

My ListView. It starts after the "Home"-button and ends at the "Search"-button:

[image: My ListView with standard scrollbar]

The functionality I want:

[image: Firefox tab view]

Can someone point me in a direction of how to achieve this?

Comment: What I would do in this situation is create a custom class that inherits from Panel or StackPanel that handles when the buttons should appear and the scrolling and use it in the <ItemsPanelTemplate> instead of the WrapPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need actually is a [TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview) control. Please check the document to learn how to use it.

[image]

It's open source, you could check its [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView) for further study.

Comment: I have tried the TabView control but it lacks some basic functionality, such as being able to not having a tab selected and detecting when a tab is clicked. I am handling all navigation myself, so the TabView does not really fit.

Comment: @Anddev That's the reason why I tell you to see its source code. If you check TabView's source code, you would see that it inherits from `ListViewBase` class. This means that it has `ItemClick` event. It should be that you want. But, please note that, you need to set `IsItemClickEnabled="True"`, then the `ItemClick` event will be fired when you click the tab.

Comment: I see - thank you! Do you know how I would be able to not have any tabs selected?